# Only master branch is built by Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitbucket

I have a GitBucket(not Bitbucket!) repository which I've connected to Jenkins with a Webhook.

Whenever I make a pull request, I would like the feature branch to be built, then merged into `master`.

The problem is that only the `master` branch is built.

In Jenkins under `Source Code Management -> Git -> Branches to build -> Branch Specifier`, I have two things: `.*/feature/.*` and `.*/master`.

My `refspec` is `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`

This should build all branches, but still, only `master` is built twice. If I try `**`, then different commits from `master` are built, but not from other branches.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins under ***Branches to build*** you have the information ***Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')***. Your configuration is specifing that only master and all branches under feature *** .*/feature/.* *** will be build.

Comment: Yes, because all branches are either `master` or `feature/something`.

Comment: what about blank so that 'any' branch is build? Else the doc indicates that :^(?!(origin/prefix)).* will match:  origin or origin/master or origin/feature